# Laravel 5.5 - Repopulate Forms After Submission

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel-5.5

I'd like to repopulate my form(s) with a users previous input after a submission (Post). The following example is not working for me. Could someone recommend a solution or a better alternative?

[View]

```
<input id="txtField" name="txtField" value="{{ old('txtField') }}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

[Controller]

```
public function showResults(){
    $field = Request::input('txtField');

    /* Note: "performQuery" is a private function 
     * that always returns a new view in the 
     * form: "view('some-view', compact('results'))" */
    return $this->performQuery($field);
}
```

[Route]

```
Route::get('/View','Controller@loadPage');
Route::post('/View','Controller@showResults');
```

Comment: Try Laravel Collective Forms. Used to be a feature of Laravel but was removed and is maintained as a separate package now. https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.4/html

Comment: Thanks, @andrewtweber I'll give it a shot

Comment: Also in your controller, after the post fails, are you redirecting back to the page? If so you probably need to call `redirect()->withInput();` so that the old input is kept

Comment: Great suggestion! I was redirecting back to the page but I didn't include the "withInput()".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once a user submits a valid form, it becomes a post request. To retrieve the submitted data, all I needed to do was change the way I asked for it.

Change: `{{ old('txtField') }} to {{ request('txtField') }}`